# Wierd formating when writing html to csv

Tags: python, html, csv, beautifulsoup

I hope someone can help me fix this..

I have a python script that finds text from tags in an html document, and I need to write them to a csv file in this format:

Nessus,ID,Text

But right now I get it in a vertical line :(

My code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import csv

with open('xx01_med_dansk') as fp:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(fp, 'html5lib')
#    print(soup.prettify())

    with open('dk_snip.csv', 'w') as f:
        wr = csv.writer(f)

        var1 = soup.find('li', text = re.compile('Scan vendor:'), attrs = {'class' : 'property_name'})
        var2 = soup.find('li', text = re.compile('Vendor ID:'), attrs = {'class' : 'property_name'})

        vendor = var1.find_next('li')
        final = vendor.string

        vend_id = var2.find_next('li')
        final2 = vend_id.text

        for dk_desc in soup.find_all(re.compile("textarea")):
            final3 = dk_desc.text

        to_csv = final+final2+final3
        wr.writerows(to_csv)
```

I am not quite sure how to format the data to input correctly in the csv file..

Html file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  
      <li class="property_name">
       <label for="id_194-description">
        Description:
       </label>
      </li>
      <li class="property_value">
       <textarea class="mceNoEditor" cols="40" id="id_194-description" name="194-description" rows="10" style="width:100%">According to its version, the installation of Oracle Database on the remote host is no longer supported.

Lack of support implies that no new security patches for the product will be released by the vendor. As a result, it is likely to contain security vulnerabilities.</textarea>
      </li>
      <li class="property_name">
       <label for="id_194-consequence">
        Consequence:
       </label>
      </li>
      <li class="property_value">
       <textarea class="mceNoEditor" cols="40" id="id_194-consequence" name="194-consequence" rows="10" style="width:100%">The remote host is running an unsupported version of a database server.</textarea>
      </li>
      <li class="property_name">
       <label for="id_194-solution">
        Solution:
       </label>
      </li>
      <li class="property_value">
       <textarea class="mceNoEditor" cols="40" id="id_194-solution" name="194-solution" rows="10" style="width:100%">Upgrade to a version of Oracle Database that is currently supported.</textarea>
      </li>
      <li class="property_name">
       <label for="id_194-cve_id">
        Cve id:
       </label>
      </li>
      <li class="property_value">
       <textarea class="mceNoEditor" cols="40" id="id_194-cve_id" maxlength="8192" name="194-cve_id" rows="10" style="width:100%; height:80px"></textarea>
      </li>
      <input id="id_194-override" name="194-override" type="hidden" value="11953"/>
      <input id="id_194-priority" name="194-priority" type="hidden"/>
      <li class="property_name">
       Vulnerability priority
      </li>
      <li class="property_value">
       <select name="prio_194">
        <option selected="selected" value="0">
         0
        </option>
       </select>
       : Oracle Database Unsupported (Nessus)
       <br/>
      </li>
      <li class="property_name">
       Save
      </li>
      <li class="property_value">
       <input type="submit" value="Save vulnerability changes"/>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </form>
    <br style="clear:both"/>
   </div>
   <div class="box">
    <h4>
     Related vulnerabilities
    </h4>
    <hr/>
    <h5>
     Oracle Database Unsupported (Nessus)
    </h5>
    <ul>
     <li class="property_name">
      Description
     </li>
     <li class="property_value">
      According to its version, the installation of Oracle Database on the remote host is no longer supported.
      <br/>
      <br/>
      Lack of support implies that no new security patches for the product will be released by the vendor. As a result, it is likely to contain security vulnerabilities.
     </li>
     <li class="property_name">
      Consequence
     </li>
     <li class="property_value">
      The remote host is running an unsupported version of a database server.
     </li>
     <li class="property_name">
      Solution
     </li>
     <li class="property_value">
      Upgrade to a version of Oracle Database that is currently supported.
     </li>
    </ul>
    <br style="clear:both"/>
   </div>
   <div class="box">
    <h4>
     Create new snippet
    </h4>
    <form action="/report/vulnerabilityEditor/?
        action=edit&amp;
        id=194&amp;
        sid=&amp;
        model=snippet" method="POST">
     <ul>
      <li class="property_name">
       <label for="id_language">
        Language:
       </label>
      </li>
      <li class="property_value">
       <select id="id_language" name="language" style="width:100%">
        <option selected="" value="1">
         Danish (DK)
        </option>
        <option value="2">
         English (EN)
        </option>
        <option value="3">
         Icelandic (IS)
        </option>
       </select>
      </li>
      <input id="id_vulnerability" name="vulnerability" type="hidden" value="194"/>
      <li class="property_name">
       <label for="id_title">
        Title:
       </label>
      </li>
      <li class="property_value">
       <input id="id_title" maxlength="100" name="title" style="width:100%" type="text"/>
      </li>
      <li class="property_name">
       <label for="id_recommendation">
        Recommendation:
       </label>
      </li>
      <li class="property_value">
       <input id="id_recommendation" maxlength="255" name="recommendation" style="width:100%" type="text"/>
      </li>
      <li class="property_name">
       <label for="id_snippet">
        Snippet:
       </label>
      </li>
      <li class="property_value">
       <textarea cols="40" id="id_snippet" name="snippet" rows="10" style="width:100%"></textarea>
      </li>
      <li class="property_name">
       Scan type
      </li>
      <li class="property_value">
       <select multiple="multiple" name="scan_type" size="6" style="width:100%">
        <option selected="selected" value="5">
         COMPANY PCI
        </option>
        <option selected="selected" value="7">
         Other
        </option>
        <option selected="selected" value="8">
         Firewall Audit
        </option>
        <option selected="selected" value="6">
         Penetration Test
        </option>
        <option selected="selected" value="9">
         WIFI Test
        </option>
        <option selected="selected" value="10">
         APP Test
        </option>
        <option selected="selected" value="1">
         External Security Analysis
        </option>
        <option selected="selected" value="2">
         Internal Security Analysis
        </option>
        <option selected="selected" value="3">
         Web Application Test
        </option>
        <option selected="selected" value="4">
         Host Discovery Analysis
        </option>
       </select>
       -- Use ctrl to mark multiple types
      </li>
      <li class="property_name">
       Save
      </li>
      <li class="property_value">
       <input type="submit" value="Save new snippet"/>
      </li>
     </ul>
     <br style="clear:both;"/>
    </form>
   </div>
   <div class="box">
    <h4>
     Edit snippets
    </h4>
    <input id="property_vulnerability_id" type="hidden" value="194"/>
    <input id="property_url_filter_snippets" type="hidden" value="/report/filterSnippets/"/>
    <ul>
     <li class="property_name">
      Language
     </li>
     <li class="property_value">
      <select id="language" name="language">
       <option value="0">
        All
       </option>
       <option value="1">
        Danish
       </option>
       <option value="2">
        English
       </option>
       <option value="3">
        Icelandic
       </option>
      </select>
     </li>
     <li class="property_name">
      Scan Type
     </li>
     <li class="property_value">
      <select id="scantype" name="scantype">
       <option value="0">
        All
       </option>
       <option value="5">
        COMPANY PCI
       </option>
       <option value="7">
        Other
       </option>
       <option value="8">
        Firewall Audit
       </option>
       <option value="6">
        Penetration Test
       </option>
       <option value="9">
        WIFI Test
       </option>
       <option value="10">
        APP Test
       </option>
       <option value="1">
        External Security Analysis
       </option>
       <option value="2">
        Internal Security Analysis
       </option>
       <option value="3">
        Web Application Test
       </option>
       <option value="4">
        Host Discovery Analysis
       </option>
      </select>
     </li>
    </ul>
    <br style="clear:both;"/>
    <div class="snippet">
     <form action="/report/vulnerabilityEditor/?action=edit&amp;id=194&amp;sid=1290&amp;model=snippet" method="POST">
      <input id="id_1290-vulnerability" name="1290-vulnerability" type="hidden" value="194"/>
      <hr/>
      <ul>
       <li class="property_name">
        <label for="id_1290-language">
         Language:
        </label>
       </li>
       <li class="property_value">
        <select id="id_1290-language" name="1290-language" style="width:100%">
         <option value="1">
          Danish (DK)
         </option>
         <option selected="" value="2">
          English (EN)
         </option>
         <option value="3">
          Icelandic (IS)
         </option>
        </select>
       </li>
       <li class="property_name">
        <label for="id_1290-title">
         Title:
        </label>
       </li>
       <li class="property_value">
        <input id="id_1290-title" maxlength="100" name="1290-title" style="width:100%" type="text" value="Oracle Database Unsupported"/>
       </li>
       <li class="property_name">
        <label for="id_1290-recommendation">
         Recommendation:
        </label>
       </li>
       <li class="property_value">
        <input id="id_1290-recommendation" maxlength="255" name="1290-recommendation" style="width:100%" type="text" value="Upgrade to a version of Oracle Database that is currently supported."/>
       </li>
       <li class="property_name">
        <label for="id_1290-snippet">
         Snippet:
        </label>
       </li>
       <li class="property_value">
        <a href="https://cyberopswiki/index.php/How_to:_Add_figure_number_in_snippet" target="_blank">
         How to: Add figure number in snippet.
        </a>
       </li>
       <li class="property_value">
        <textarea cols="40" id="id_1290-snippet" name="1290-snippet" rows="10" style="width:100%">&lt;p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt: auto; mso-margin-bottom-alt: auto; text-align: justify; line-height: normal;"&gt;&lt;span lang="EN-US" style="font-size: 10pt;"&gt;It has been detected, that the installed version of Oracle Application Server is&amp;nbsp;&lt;strong&gt;XXXX.&amp;nbsp;&lt;/strong&gt;This version is known to be vulnerable to a number of unspecified vulnerabilities, categorized as 'urgent'.&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt: auto; mso-margin-bottom-alt: auto; text-align: justify; line-height: normal;"&gt;&lt;span lang="EN-US" style="font-size: 10pt;"&gt;As this version is no longer supported for this platform, updates or patches may no longer be released, which have the consequence that vulnerabilities can not be patched, leaving the system vulnerable.&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt: auto; mso-margin-bottom-alt: auto; text-align: justify; line-height: normal;"&gt;&lt;span lang="EN-US" style="font-size: 10pt;"&gt;In version 10.1.2.0.2 there are, according to http://www.cvedetails.com more than 54 vulnerabilities which affects the installed version.&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt: auto; mso-margin-bottom-alt: auto; text-align: center; line-height: normal;" align="center"&gt;&lt;strong&gt;&lt;em&gt;&lt;span lang="EN-US" style="font-size: 8pt;"&gt;Figure 1: &lt;/span&gt;&lt;/em&gt;&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;em&gt;&lt;span lang="EN-US" style="font-size: 8pt;"&gt;Oracle Application Server version.&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/em&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt: auto; mso-margin-bottom-alt: auto; text-align: justify; line-height: normal;"&gt;&lt;span lang="EN-US" style="font-size: 10pt;"&gt;More information on these vulnerabilities can be found at:&amp;nbsp;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;span style="font-size: 10pt;"&gt;&lt;a href="http://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-93/product_id-707/version_id-26592/Oracle-Application-Server-10.1.2.0.2.html"&gt;&lt;span lang="EN-US" style="color: blue; mso-ansi-language: EN-US;"&gt;http://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-93/product_id-707/version_id-26592/Oracle-Application-Server-10.1.2.0.2.html&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;a href="http://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-93/product_id-707/version_id-26592/Oracle-Application-Server-10.1.2.0.2.html"&gt;&lt;span lang="EN-US" style="color: blue; mso-ansi-language: EN-US;"&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;span lang="EN-US" style="font-size: 10pt;"&gt;.&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt: auto; mso-margin-bottom-alt: auto; text-align: justify; line-height: normal;"&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt: auto; mso-margin-bottom-alt: auto; text-align: justify; line-height: normal;"&gt;&lt;span lang="EN-US" style="font-size: 10pt;"&gt;It is recommended that the installed version is updated as soon as possible to the latest version.&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;</textarea>
       </li>
       <li class="property_name">
        Scan type
       </li>
       <li class="property_value">
        <select multiple="multiple" name="scan_type" size="6" style="width:100%">
         <option selected="selected" value="5">
          COMPANY PCI
         </option>
         <option selected="selected" value="7">
          Other
         </option>
         <option selected="selected" value="8">
          Firewall Audit
         </option>
         <option selected="selected" value="6">
          Penetration Test
         </option>
         <option selected="selected" value="9">
          WIFI Test
         </option>
         <option selected="selected" value="10">
          APP Test
         </option>
         <option selected="selected" value="1">
          External Security Analysis
         </option>
         <option selected="selected" value="2">
          Internal Security Analysis
         </option>
         <option selected="selected" value="3">
          Web Application Test
         </option>
         <option selected="selected" value="4">
          Host Discovery Analysis
         </option>
        </select>
        -- Use ctrl to mark multiple types
       </li>
       <li class="property_name">
        Update
       </li>
       <li class="property_value">
        <input type="submit" value="Update snippet"/>
       </li>
      </ul>
     </form>
     <br style="clear:both;"/>
    </div>
    <div class="snippet">
     <form action="/report/vulnerabilityEditor/?action=edit&amp;id=194&amp;sid=172&amp;model=snippet" method="POST">
      <input id="id_172-vulnerability" name="172-vulnerability" type="hidden" value="194"/>
      <hr/>
      <ul>
       <li class="property_name">
        <label for="id_172-language">
         Language:
        </label>
       </li>
       <li class="property_value">
        <select id="id_172-language" name="172-language" style="width:100%">
         <option selected="" value="1">
          Danish (DK)
         </option>
         <option value="2">
          English (EN)
         </option>
         <option value="3">
          Icelandic (IS)
         </option>
        </select>
       </li>
       <li class="property_name">
        <label for="id_172-title">
         Title:
        </label>
       </li>
       <li class="property_value">
        <input id="id_172-title" maxlength="100" name="172-title" style="width:100%" type="text" value="Forældet Oracle Application Server 10g"/>
       </li>
       <li class="property_name">
        <label for="id_172-recommendation">
         Recommendation:
        </label>
       </li>
       <li class="property_value">
        <input id="id_172-recommendation" maxlength="255" name="172-recommendation" style="width:100%" type="text"/>
       </li>
       <li class="property_name">
        <label for="id_172-snippet">
         Snippet:
        </label>
       </li>
       <li class="property_value">
        <a href="https://cyberopswiki/index.php/How_to:_Add_figure_number_in_snippet" target="_blank">
         How to: Add figure number in snippet.
        </a>
       </li>
       <li class="property_value">
        <textarea cols="40" id="id_172-snippet" name="172-snippet" rows="10" style="width:100%">&lt;p style="font-size: 13px;"&gt;Det konstateret, at den installerede version af Oracle Application Server er&amp;nbsp;&lt;strong&gt;XXXX.&amp;nbsp;&lt;/strong&gt;Denne version indeholder flere kendte samt uspecificeret s&amp;aring;rbarheder, der kategoriseres som v&amp;aelig;rende 'yderst kritiske' og 'kritiske'.&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p style="font-size: 13px;"&gt;Da der ikke l&amp;aelig;ngere komme opdateringer til denne platform, vil disse s&amp;aring;rbarheder ikke blive udbedret, hvorfor systemet er meget udsat.&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p style="font-size: 13px;"&gt;I version 10.1.2.0.2 findes der if&amp;oslash;lge http://www.cvedetails.com ikke mindre end 54 s&amp;aring;rbarheder, der ber&amp;oslash;rer denne version. Mere information om disse findes p&amp;aring; adressen&amp;nbsp;&lt;a href="http://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-93/product_id-707/version_id-26592/Oracle-Application-Server-10.1.2.0.2.html"&gt;http://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-93/product_id-707/version_id-26592/Oracle-Application-Server-10.1.2.0.2.html&lt;/a&gt;&lt;a href="http://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-93/product_id-707/version_id-26592/Oracle-Application-Server-10.1.2.0.2.html"&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/a&gt;.&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p style="font-size: 13px;"&gt;Det anbefales leverand&amp;oslash;ren af software l&amp;oslash;sningen kontakts, s&amp;aring; der hurtigst muligt kan opgraderes til en nyere, supporteret version.&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;</textarea>
       </li>
```

As per Martins suggestions I have modified the code as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import csv
import glob

def get_danish(text):
    return re.compile(r'\b({0})\b'.format(text), flags=re.IGNORECASE).search

with open('dk_snip.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_out:
    csv_out = csv.writer(f_out)
#    csv_out.writerow(["Nessus", "ID", "Descrip"])

    for filename in glob.glob('/home/rj/Documents/snip/snips/*'):
        print("Processing:", filename)

        with open(filename) as f_in:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(f_in, 'html5lib')


            var1 = soup.find('li', text = re.compile('Scan vendor:'), attrs = {'class' : 'property_name'})
            var2 = soup.find('li', text = re.compile('Vendor ID:'), attrs = {'class' : 'property_name'})

            vendor = var1.find_next('li').get_text(strip=True)
            vend_id = var2.find_next('li').get_text(strip=True)

#    rows = [[vendor, vend_id, dk_desc.get_text(strip=True)] for dk_desc in soup.find_all("textarea")[:3]]


            for textarea in soup.find_all("textarea"):
                desc = textarea.get_text(strip=True)

                if get_danish('dette'):
                    csv_out.writerows([vendor, vend_id, desc])
```

Comment: Instead of `to_csv = final+final2+final3`, can you try `to_csv = [final, final2, final3]`

Comment: This just makes every char comma seperated, like this: `", , , , , , , ,N,e,s,s,u,s,"`

Comment: I think this is what you want to achieve : 
`to_csv = [(x,y,z) for x,y,z in zip(final1, final2, final3)]`

Comment: Nope, that just take first 3 char from each line and comma seperates them: `<,"
",<
p, ,p
 , , 
s, ,s
t, ,t
y, ,y
l, ,l
e, ,e
=,5,=
"""",5,""""
f,7,f
o,8,o
n,6,n
t,"
",t
`

Comment: There are a lot of textareas, not 1. How do you intend combining them all into a single column? Or should each have its own column?

Comment: @bash_me_silly, missed one more thing. instead of `wr.writerows(to_csv)` try `wr.writerow(to_csv)`

Answer (score 0):

The tags you are getting need to be stripped. One way to do this is to use the BeautifulSoup [`.get_text(strip=True)`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) function.

I am assuming that for each `textarea` you want to repeat the `Nessus` and `ID` values. The following shows how this could be done:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import re
import glob
import random

def get_language(text):
    # This will need to be added using another library - currently random
    return random.choice(["en", "dk"])


with open('dk_snip.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_out:
    csv_out = csv.writer(f_out)
    csv_out.writerow(["Nessus", "ID", "Text"])

    for filename in glob.glob('*.html'):        # search all HTML files in the current folder
        print("Processing:", filename)

        with open(filename) as f_in:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(f_in, 'html5lib')

            var1 = soup.find('li', text=re.compile('Scan vendor:'), attrs = {'class' : 'property_name'})
            var2 = soup.find('li', text=re.compile('Vendor ID:'), attrs = {'class' : 'property_name'})

            nessus = var1.find_next('li').get_text(strip=True)
            id = var2.find_next('li').get_text(strip=True)

            for textarea in soup.find_all("textarea"):
                desc = textarea.get_text(strip=True)

                if get_language(desc) == 'dk':
                    csv_out.writerow([nessus, id, desc])
```

Which would give you the following output CSV file:

```
Nessus,ID,Text
Nessus,55786,"According to its version, the installation of Oracle Database on the remote host is no longer supported.

Lack of support implies that no new security patches for the product will be released by the vendor. As a result, it is likely to contain security vulnerabilities."
Nessus,55786,The remote host is running an unsupported version of a database server.
Nessus,55786,Upgrade to a version of Oracle Database that is currently supported.
```

Note: As your text contains newlines, the CSV format automatically wraps these cells with double quotes. It will load correctly into another package.

The script search all matching files in a the current folder. For each `textarea`, a call is made to `get_language()` which needs to be coded using another library. If `dk` is detected (or whatever is needed) then that line is added to the CSV file.

If your textarea contains HTML, you might need to further process it using another call to BeautifulSoup:

```
soup_desc = BeautifulSoup(desc, 'html5lib')

for text in soup_desc.stripped_strings:
    ...
```

Comment: Hey Martin.. The thing is I only need the danish description text, and as far as I can see (I have around 1500 textfiles with text I need to loop through and convert to a single csv file), all the files have Nessus and its ID, but the danish text is not present in all files.. The first 5 textarea I can always disregard, but the 6th is sometimes present (and is the english text), and the 7th is usualy the danish text. However sometimes the english is missing and then the danish text is in the 6th textarea (its pita I know!)

Comment: Maybe it would be possible to check if there is 7 textareas and then take the last, otherwise take the 6th? I dont know..

Comment: There are libraries that could help you identify the text language. You could then loop over all areas and only save those that are Danish?

Comment: A loop could also be added to walk over all of your files and then add the output to the same CSV file, I could add that to the answer.

Comment: What would be great, I have also been struggling with creating the loop

Comment: I have updated the answer to show how you could progress.

Comment: with your changes, I get the following output:                                         `N,e,s,s,u,s
5,5,7,8,6
A,c,c,o,r,d,i,n,g, ,t,o, ,i,t,s, ,v,e,r,s,i,o,n,",", ,t,h,e, ,i,n,s,t,a,l,l,a,t,i,o,n, ,o,f, ,O,r,a,c,l,e, ,D,a,t,a,b,a,s,e, ,o,n, ,t,h,e, ,r,e,m,o,t,e, ,h,o,s,t, ,i,s, ,n,o, ,l,o,n,g,e,r, ,s,u,p,p,o,r,t,e,d,.,"
","
",L,a,c,k, ,o,f, ,s,u,p,p,o,r,t, ,i,m,p,l,i,e,s, ,t,h,a,t, ,n,o, ,n,e,w, ,s,e,c,u,r,i,t,y, ,p,a,t,c,h,e,s, ,f,o,r, ,t,h,e, ,p,r,o,d,u,c,t,` Idealy vendor, id and desc should be on the same line aswell.. but the loop works perfectly

Comment: Right now vendor is on line 1, id on line 2 and desc on the followling line

Comment: You have modified the code to use `.writerows()` which is wrong. You need `.writerow()`

Comment: I still get all the "textarea" text as output, but at least its formatted correcly now.. Heres my attempt at trying to check if position 6,7 are empty: `for textarea in soup.find_all("textarea"):
                print(len(textarea))
                if (len(textarea) >= 7):
                    desc = textarea[7].get_text(strip=True)
                elif (len(textarea) == 6):
                    desc = textarea[6].get_text(strip=True)
                elif (len(textarea) < 6):
                    desc = "unknown"`

Comment: `textarea` is a BeautifulSoup element tag object, not a string. I think this is moving into a completely new question. I suggest you group a number of possible texts together and ask a new question on how to extract the ones you need (make the code as simple as possible to recreate your problem).